# Hardhat deploy script on RSK throws UND_ERR_SOCKET

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy, rsk

I'm using Hardhat to deploy a smart contract, it's deployed successfully to Polygon, but when trying to deploy into RSK, it fails with -

```bash
$ npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network rsk

SocketError: closed
    at Socket.onSocketClose (./node_modules/undici/lib/client.js:967:31)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:675:12) {
  code: 'UND_ERR_SOCKET',
  socket: {
    localAddress: undefined,
    localPort: undefined,
    remoteAddress: undefined,
    remotePort: undefined,
    remoteFamily: undefined,
    timeout: undefined,
    bytesWritten: 209,
    bytesRead: 125
  }
}
```

In `hardhat.config.js`, RSK is defined as following -

```
    ...
    networks: {
        rsk: {
            url: '...',
            accounts: [...],
            timeout: 120000,
        },
        polygon: {
            url: '...',
            accounts: [...],
        },
    },
    ...
```

1. It happens on two different synced local [RSKJ](https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj) nodes, same result - but works on the public `https://public-node.rsk.co` node.
2. It worked in the past on my local nodes, nothing changed since! (that I know of)

So what could be the issue with my local RSK nodes?

Comment: can you share the full `networks.rsk` object in the hardhat config file pls? (redact any seed phrases or private keys, of course)

Comment: if you're using a custom config for your local RSKj node, can you also pls share the RSK config file? plus the command that you're using to start the RSKj node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardhat v2.9.7 uses `undici` v4, whereas subsequent versions use `undici` v5.

To reproduce the error, run this command, then run the test script below.

```shell
npm i --exact undici@4
```

Subsequently, run this command (to switch to newer `undici` version),
then run the test script below again.

```shell
npm i --exact undici@5
```

**Underlying cause**:
`undici` v5 expects a HTTP response to include
either a `content-length` heading or a `transfer-encoding` header.
The previous version, `undici` v4 does not have this requirement.

**Workaround**:
Downgrade to earlier version of `hardhat`: v2.9.7

**Solution**:
Fix in RSKj that sends the expected headers.

---

**Test Script**

```js
const { Client } = require('undici');
const rskRpcUrl =
  process.env.RSK_RPC_URL ||
  'https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co/'; // public node
  // e.g. 'http://localhost:4444/' for local node
const client = new Client(rskRpcUrl);

client.request({
  path: '/',
  method: 'POST',
  body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_chainId","params":[],"id":67}',
  headers: ["Content-Type", "application/json"],
}, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return
  }

  const {
    statusCode,
    headers,
    trailers,
    body
  } = data

  console.log('response received', statusCode)
  console.log('headers', headers)

  body.setEncoding('utf8')
  body.on('data', console.log)
  body.on('end', () => {
    console.log('trailers', trailers)
  })

  client.close()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is fixed in HOP-4.1.0, now. https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj/commit/554e549821c05b9977f4f1df1a53cb69e8f5e8b1